# How to define a colormap in matplotlib using HSV colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, hsv, colormap

I'd like to define a colormap in matlplotlib that ranges from one color to another, both specified in HSV, not RGB.

Since interpolation in HSV is not the same as interpolation in RGB, I cannot use the LinearSegmentedColormap method using the corresponding RGB colors. Or can I?

How could I define such colormap?

Comment: You could do the interpolation yourself, over the range for a set number of color levels (256?) and then convert each of those HSV colors to RGB, to give to `LinearSegmentedColormap`